# mysql find words in string and sort by "most matches"

Tags: mysql

I have a table as:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|author_id   |  content                                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 54         | I ate an apple and an orange for breakfast.   |
| 63         | Going to the store.                           |
| 12         | Should I wear the orange shirt?               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I want to find rows with the words `apple , orange`
running the query 
`SELECT * FROM books WHERE content LIKE "%apple%" OR content LIKE "%orange%"`

returns the correct value, but because true queries will contain more than 2 values, I was wondering if I can tell sql to sort the results by most matches, e.g the rows with both apple and orange first

Comment: Have you considered [full-text indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: You can also use length and replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MATCH(..) AGAINST (... IN BOOLEAN MODE)` to calculate a relevance on which you can `ORDER BY` 
But to use it you have to add a FULLTEXT index like tadman said in the comments.

```
SELECT 
 *
 , MATCH (Test.content) AGAINST ('apple orange' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM 
 Test
WHERE 
 MATCH (Test.content) AGAINST ('apple orange' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY 
 MATCH (Test.content) AGAINST ('apple orange' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC

| author_id | content                                     | relevance            |
| --------- | ------------------------------------------- | -------------------- |
| 54        | I ate an apple and an orange for breakfast. | 0.25865283608436584  |
| 12        | Should I wear the orange shirt?             | 0.031008131802082062 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qsVnDjsHRMpVz4xJAmN8dY/0)

Comment: That's great, wasn't familier with fulltext
What about security issues if it's a user's input? (injection)

Comment: general rule @DsCpp always use prepared statements when working with a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interest in the number of times a same word can appear within a `content`, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (content LIKE "%orange%") + (content LIKE "%apple%") AS matches
FROM
  test
WHERE
  content LIKE "%orange%"
OR
  content LIKE "%apple%"
ORDER BY
  matches DESC;
```

Online example:

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vQEy9LYnvsvxiDTLkcYzRP/0)

Comment: Nice idea only problem with this is `LIKE "%...%"` can never use indexing..

Comment: Yeah, you right, this could present poor performance on a table with much data.