# How To Order By Adding Total Of All Columns With INT Values?

Tags: php, mysql

**NOTE:**
My thread was wrongfully closed by someone claiming following link answers my question and this is duplicate thread.
Wrong! Following thread does not answer my question as it is completely a different topic.
[mysql find words in string and sort by "most matches"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116594/mysql-find-words-in-string-and-sort-by-most-matches)

**MY ORIGINAL POST:**
I need to learn 2 SQL queries that count all the points from more than one column and orders the rows based on most points in descending order.

EXAMPLE 1:
I do a keyword search for "mobile phone tutorial apps". Note 4 words.
Sql should find all the rows that contain any of these 4 keywords.
That means, since I searched for 4 keywords, sql should even pull-up those rows that just have even 1 or 2 or 3 of these 4 keywords in them.

Say, my mysql table looks like this, where "kw" = "keyword":

```
id |  kw1   | kw1_point |   kw2   |  kw2_point  |   kw3   | kw3_point |    kw4     | kw4_point 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  |  mobile |    3    |  phone  |     3       |  apps    |     2    |    tutorial  |    2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  mobile |    1    |  phone  |     1       |  apps    |     3    |    tutorial  |    3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | tutorial |   3   |   apps   |     3       |  mobile  |     2    |   phone      |    3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  |  mobile |    5    |  tutorial     |      5       |  apps     |      5     |    usa        |    5
```

NOTE: All 4 keywords exists on the first 3 matching rows. However, only 3 words exist in the final matching row.
And the final matching row's keywords are not in the order of my keyword search.
here in Q1, this should not matter. Sql should ignore in which order the keywords are in each column when comparing the order of my searched keywords. All it should do, is:

**A). Find matching rows, regardless of how many of my searched keywords exist on each row;
B). Count the totals of each points, (count more than one column in this case), in each row; And
C) List the rows in the point's descending order.**

As you can see, from my example, the following are the keyword points of each row after calculating ALL their keyword points (all point columns):

```
id 0 = 10 points
id 1 = 8 points
id 2 = 11 points
id 3 = 20
```

So, in this case, the SQL query should present rows in this descending order:

```
id 3 = 20
id 2 = 11 points
id 0 = 10 points
id 1 = 8 points
```

```
id |  kw1   | kw1_point |   kw2   |  kw2_point  |   kw3   | kw3_point |    kw4     | kw4_point 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  |  mobile |    5    |  tutorial |   5       |  apps    |    5     |    usa    |    5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | tutorial |   3   |   apps    |    3       |  mobile  |    2     |   phone   |    3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  |  mobile |    3    |  phone  |     3       |  apps    |     2    |    tutorial  |    2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  mobile |    1    |  phone  |     1       |  apps    |     3    |    tutorial  |    3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Had there been only a single "keyword point" (kw1_point) to calculate, then I would have written the SQL like this using prepared statements:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from keywords WHERE kw1 = ? OR kw2 = ? OR kw3 = ? OR kw4 = ? order by kw1_point desc LIMIT 100";
```

The confusion arises when there is more than one column's values to count.
Now the next question ...

Q2.
I need an SQL query that will behave similar to Q1 but rows with less number of keyword matches should be given less priority.
So, in this case, from my example, SQL should present in this order:

```
id 2 = 11 points
id 0 = 10 points
id 1 = 8 points
**id 3 = 20**
**id 4 = 50**
```

```
id |  kw1   | kw1_point |   kw2   |  kw2_point  |   kw3   | kw3_point |    kw4     | kw4_point 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | tutorial |   3   |   apps    |    3       |  mobile  |    2     |   phone   |    3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  |  mobile |    3    |  phone  |     3       |  apps    |     2    |    tutorial  |    2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  mobile |    1    |  phone  |     1       |  apps    |     3    |    tutorial  |    3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  |  mobile |    5    |  tutorial |   5       |  apps    |    5     |    usa    |    5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4  |  cell   |    50   |  phone   |      50    |  uk     |    50     |    prices  |   50
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NOTE: id3 had the highest point (excluding id4) but it was listed below the other 3 rows (id0, id1 & id2) due to the fact that it only had 3 matching keywords while the other 3 above it had 4 matching keywords.
So the less the matching keywords, the bad the ranking.

NOTE: id4 had more points that id3, but it was ranked below id3 due to the fact that it had less matching keywords than id 3. Only one matching keyword "phone".

Tried googling for answers but no results. Not even on this website.

Comment: No one can help ?

Comment: @Your Common Sense - Not even you ?

Comment: have you tried something like **order by (kw1_point + kw2_point + kw3_point + kw4_point) desc**?

Comment: @imvain2 - No. I have not tried because I do not know that particular query. Sql is my weakness. Anyway, are you sure that will work ? It seems logical. I might aswell try it. - Thanks!

Comment: I ran a similar order by on a mySQL table of my own. The query just adds all of the values in each row and sorts by that value in descending order.

Comment: @imvain2 - Sorry mate! But mysql only shows 1 row: id0. Even though other rows have these matching keywords. See above for my mysql table. Sql I used: SELECT * from keywords WHERE id = ? OR date_and_time = ? OR kw_1 = ? OR = ? OR kw_2 = ? OR = ? OR kw_3 = ? OR = ? OR kw_4 = ? ORDER BY (kw_1_point+kw_2_point+kw_3_point+kw_4_point) DESC.

Comment: Order by doesn't affect row count, order by just affects how the results are sorted.

Comment: @imvain2 - Can you re-open my thread ? My thread was wrongfully closed by someone claiming following link answers my question and this is duplicate thread. Wrong! Following thread does not answer my question as it is completely a different topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116594/mysql-find-words-in-string-and-sort-by-most-matches